# Upgraded from Outlook 2000 to Outlook 2010, missing all of the contacts email address's

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts

Everything from 2000 imported to 2010, except all of the contacts email address's are missing.  How do I recover them and why did they magically disappear?

Comment: You are missing the .nk2 file I assume?

Comment: How did you do the import? Did you do an export/import with Excel or CSV or direct from the PST file?